# Git remote succeeded, but no data on remote site

Tags: git

I am trying to commit the changes to a directory of mine on a remote server. So I set on the local server:

```
git remote add origin ssh://....

git push --all origin
```

collecting an error, so I did:

```
 git push origin master -f
```

and again after another failure:

```
 git push --set-upstream origin master
```

on the server I previously did:

```
git reset --hard
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

at that point the transfer appeared correctly executed, but nothing appears on the remote site. This is the result of a few commands:

```
git remote show origin
```

local server (messages are in Italian, but they should be clear anyway)

> Fetch URL: ...
>   branch HEAD: master   Branch remoto:
>       master tracked   Branch locale configurato per 'git pull':
>       master merge con il remote master   Ref locale configurato per 'git push':
>       master pushes to master (aggiornato)

while executing on the remote server:

```
git log
```

correctly reports the commits.

If I do:

```
git checkout
```

it lists all the files in my local directory prefixed by a D, like they were to be deleted.

If I now try again on the local server:

```
git push
```

it returns:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the (relevant) output from running `git status` on the remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your target repository is up to date and points to the latest pushed commit, but nothing is checked out.

With push you can only change the repository itself (.git directory) but not the checked out files.

You need to run a checkout or reset on the target folder to check out the latest changes in the repository, for example:

```
git reset --hard master
```

This can be done automatically using [githooks](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).

Comment: Right, after the command, all the files are at their correct place even on the remote server. Now the push to remote also work on Xcode! Thank you very much. So it looks the sequence I used is fine with the addition of your command.

Comment: Yet, after having pushed the commit from Xcode, the new files added in the commit do not appear in the remote site. Should I execute your command each time I put the content, or what else?

Comment: You have to check out / reset the files after each push. This is what you can automate with githooks.

Comment: And which command should I execute manually and which one to trigger the thing automatically?  If I execute: git reset --hard master I always end up to a past release.

Comment: I executed git checkout on the latest commit id in the local copy. Is there some way to automatically do it as soon as a commit is performed?

Answer (score -1):

This is the present result (funnily in Italian, 'eliminato' stand for "'deleted' of:

```
git status
```

git status

## Sul branch master

## Changes to be committed:

## (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

#

## eliminato:    Allotted-Time.png

## eliminato:    Allotted-Time@2x.png

## eliminato:    Base.lproj/Dhammapada.html

## eliminato:    Base.lproj/FlipsideView.xib

## eliminato:    Base.lproj/InfoPlist.strings

## eliminato:    Base.lproj/Localizable.strings

## eliminato:    Base.lproj/StoryboardiPad.storyboard

## eliminato:    Base.lproj/StoryboardiPhone.storyboard

## eliminato:    Base.lproj/iPuja-Info.plist

## eliminato:    Buddha_silhouetteBig.png

## eliminato:    Buddha_silhouetteBig@2x.png

## eliminato:    Buddha_silhouetteSmall.png

## eliminato:    Buddha_silhouetteSmall@2x.png

## eliminato:    Calendar-Month.png

## eliminato:    Calendar-Month@2x.png

## eliminato:    Classes/MainViewController.h

## eliminato:    Classes/MainViewController.m

## eliminato:    Classes/backDhammapada.png

## eliminato:    Classes/backDhammapada@2x.png

## eliminato:    Classes/backDhammapadaiPad.png

## eliminato:    Classes/backDhammapadaiPad@2x.png

## eliminato:    Classes/backGong.png

## eliminato:    Classes/backGong@2x.png

## eliminato:    Classes/backGongiPad.png

## eliminato:    Classes/backGongiPad@2x.png

## eliminato:    Classes/iPuja_ProAppDelegate.h

## eliminato:    Classes/iPuja_ProAppDelegate.m

## eliminato:    Default-568h@2x.png

## eliminato:    Default-Portrait~ipad.png

## eliminato:    Default.png

## eliminato:    Default@2x.png

## eliminato:    DhammapadaController.h

## eliminato:    DhammapadaController.m

## eliminato:    EMPTY_ALBUM_FILE_NAME.png

## eliminato:    EMPTY_ALBUM_FILE_NAME@2x.png

## eliminato:    Entitlements.plist

## eliminato:    FlipsideViewController.h

## eliminato:    FlipsideViewController.m

## eliminato:    Icon-120.png

## eliminato:    Icon-60.png

## eliminato:    Icon-60x60@2x.png

## eliminato:    Icon-72.png

## eliminato:    Icon.png

## eliminato:    Icon@2x.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon120-1.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon120.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon180.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon29.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon40.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon58-1.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon58.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon76x76.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon76x76@2x.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon80-1.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon80.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon87.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Contents.json

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-568h@2x.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default@2x.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/defaultiPuja-Landscape@2x~ipad.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/defaultiPuja-Landscape~ipad.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/defaultiPujaPortrait@2x~ipad.png

## eliminato:    Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/defaultiPujaPortrait~ipad.png

## eliminato:    Intermediate.aiff

## eliminato:    Lotus@.png

## eliminato:    Lotus@2x.png

## eliminato:    MMPDeepSleepPreventer.h

## eliminato:    MMPDeepSleepPreventer.m

## eliminato:    MMPSilence.wav

## eliminato:    MainView.xib

## eliminato:    PujaViewController.h

## eliminato:    PujaViewController.m

## eliminato:    Settings.bundle/Root.plist

## eliminato:    Settings.bundle/en.lproj/Root.strings

## eliminato:    Settings.bundle/it.lproj/Root.strings

## eliminato:    Sound.png

## eliminato:    Sound@2x.png

## eliminato:    calendarManagement.swift

## eliminato:    chime.aiff

## eliminato:    chime.m4a

## eliminato:    chimeLong.m4a

## eliminato:    defaultiPuja-Landscape@2x~ipad.png

## eliminato:    defaultiPuja-Landscape~ipad.png

## eliminato:    defaultiPujaPortrait@2x~ipad.png

## eliminato:    defaultiPujaPortrait~ipad.png

## eliminato:    dhammapadaSingleton.h

## eliminato:    dhammapadaSingleton.m

## eliminato:    en.lproj/Dhammapada.html

## eliminato:    en.lproj/FlipsideView.strings

## eliminato:    en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings

## eliminato:    en.lproj/Localizable.strings

## eliminato:    en.lproj/StoryboardiPad.strings

## eliminato:    en.lproj/StoryboardiPhone.strings

## eliminato:    gong1min.aup

## eliminato:    gong1min_data/e00/d00/e00003a4.au

## eliminato:    gong1min_data/e00/d00/e000073f.au

## eliminato:    gong1min_data/e00/d00/e0000dc8.au

## eliminato:    gongiPad.png

## eliminato:    gongiPad@2x.png

## eliminato:    iPad/MainWindow-iPad.xib

## eliminato:    iPhone-app.png

## eliminato:    iPhone-app@2x.png

## eliminato:    iPodConfiguration.h

## eliminato:    iPodConfiguration.m

## eliminato:    iPodConfiguration.xib

## eliminato:    iPuja-Bridging-Header.h

## eliminato:    iPuja.entitlements

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/fbartolom.mode1v3

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/fbartolom.pbxuser

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/fbartolom.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState (MacBook-di-Fabrizio's conflicted copy 2011-06-17).xcuserstate

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/fbartolom.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/fbartolom.xcuserdatad/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/fbartolom.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints.xcbkptlist

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/fbartolom.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/fbartolom.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/iPuja.xcscheme

## eliminato:    iPuja.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/fbartolom.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist

## eliminato:    iPuja_Pro_Prefix.pch

## eliminato:    iTunes1024.png

## eliminato:    icon120.png

## eliminato:    icon180.png

## eliminato:    icon29.png

## eliminato:    icon40.png

## eliminato:    icon58.png

## eliminato:    icon76x76.png

## eliminato:    icon76x76@2x.png

## eliminato:    icon76x76x3.png

## eliminato:    icon80.png

## eliminato:    icon87.png

## eliminato:    icon_60@3x.png

## eliminato:    it.lproj/Dhammapada.html

## eliminato:    it.lproj/FlipsideView.strings

## eliminato:    it.lproj/Info.plist

## eliminato:    it.lproj/InfoPlist.strings

## eliminato:    it.lproj/Localizable.strings

## eliminato:    it.lproj/StoryboardiPad.strings

## eliminato:    it.lproj/StoryboardiPhone.strings

## eliminato:    it.lproj/iPuja-Info.plist

## eliminato:    it.lproj/iPuja_Pro-Info.plist

## eliminato:    main.m

## eliminato:    pauseGreen.png

## eliminato:    pauseGreen@2x.png

## eliminato:    playGreen.png

## eliminato:    playGreen@2x.png

## eliminato:    shareView.png

## eliminato:    shareView@2x.png

## eliminato:    share_this_icon.png

## eliminato:    share_this_icon@2x.png

## eliminato:    singleMeditationViewController.h

## eliminato:    singleMeditationViewController.m

## eliminato:    stick.png

## eliminato:    stick@2x.png

## eliminato:    stickiPad.png

## eliminato:    stickiPad@2x.png

## eliminato:    th.lproj/Dhammapada.html

## eliminato:    th.lproj/FlipsideView.strings

## eliminato:    th.lproj/InfoPlist.strings

## eliminato:    th.lproj/Localizable.strings

## eliminato:    th.lproj/StoryboardiPad.strings

## eliminato:    th.lproj/StoryboardiPhone.strings

## eliminato:    th.lproj/iPuja-Info.plist

## eliminato:    tuneAssistedViewController.h

## eliminato:    tuneAssistedViewController.m